# I want to delete a specific patient from my array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to delete a patient from the array ,Is that possible in
my situation, I have looked for examples and I couldn't find similar
scenarios.Can anyone show me how to delete a patient if that is
possible.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57113238bde91693e9ff69e7"),
    "docname" : "Arthur Hovsepyan",
    "job_desc" : "Hepatologist",
    "sex" : "male",
    "jobtype" : "fulltime",
    "office" : "room 448",
    "email" : "arturchik@hotmail.com",
    "phone_number" : 862124343,
    "address" : "68 Peterburg street,waterford",
    "hours" : 12,
    "patients" : [
        {
            "name" : "Jenny Power",
            "ward_no" : 1,
            "sex" : "female",
            "termdays" : 2,
            "illness_type" : "minor",
            "age" : 22,
            "phone_number" : 877285221,
            "address" : "63 Johnston street ,Waterford"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Marie Peters",
            "ward_no" : 2,
            "sex" : "female",
            "termdays" : 0,
            "illness_type" : "minor",
            "age" : 21,
            "phone_number" : 862145992,
            "address" : "99 Grange,Waterford"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Philip John",
            "ward_no" : 2,
            "sex" : "male",
            "termdays" : 10,
            "illness_type" : "serious",
            "age" : 31,
            "phone_number" : 861125981,
            "address" : "12 Monvoy Bridge,Waterford"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Marta Peters",
            "ward_no" : 3,
            "sex" : "female",
            "termd7ays" : 0,
            "illness_type" : "minor",
            "age" : 31,
            "phone_number" : 862125981,
            "address" : "100 Grange Manor,Waterford"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result for your query?

Comment: The result would be that for example Marie Peters  and all her details would be deleted from the array

Comment: Are you putting real data up or test data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

You want

```
db.foo.update({}, {
    $pull: { 
        patients: {
            name: "Jenny Power"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You should use [`updateOne`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#db.collection.updateOne) or [`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany) because `update()` is deprecated.

Comment: Deprecation notices are lagging a bit in the shell, but it doesn't make the general statement by @user3100115 untrue. No-one is going to write an "application" in the "shell" afterall. So it's probably an `.updateOne()` with the `_id` of the target document. Also see the `@` thingy? That's the only way people know you are talking to "them". Otherwise your comments are just "talking to yourself".